# Mockito multiple ObjectMapper values

Tags: java, java-8, objectmapper

im mocking mapper.convertValue to return 2 different return type of same class.

```
Target target1 = new Target();
target1.setId("123);

Target target2 = new Target();
target2.setId("345);

 Mockito.when(mapper.convertValue(anyMap(), eq(Target.class))).thenReturn(target1);
 Mockito.when(mapper.convertValue(anyMap(), eq(Target.class))).thenReturn(target2);
```

The actual code is called this way , where i want to mock the objectmapper to return target1 or target2 depending on the pair. Right now its overriding one over the other in order i have defined.

```
List<Pair<String, Target>> targetPairs = targetPairList.entrySet().stream()
                .map(pair -> ImmutablePair.of(pair.getKey(), mapper.convertValue(pair.getValue().getSourceAsMap(), Target.class)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
Mockito.when(mapper.convertValue(anyMap(), eq(Target.class))).then(invocationOnMock -> {
  if (invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0] == givenObjectOne) {
    return target1;
  } else if (invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0] == givenObjectTwo) {
    return target2;
  }
  return null;
});
```

More details about Answer from Mockito can be found here. https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.2/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply . What is going to givenObjectOne or givenObjectTwo here ? As it’s going to be 2 mock objects for me depending on the pair .

Comment: If you need to give mocks based on the input arguments this is the way. You can also modify this to give mocks based on the invocation count